# How to update built-in clang to latest version on macos

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I have rm-rf the command line tool folder and reinstalled them.
But the clang version is still not latest.

```bash
clang -v
```

We get clang 14.0

```
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

But now clang 16.0 is released.

Comment: Apple clang is the clang compiler provided directly by Apple. If you want to install a non-Apple clang you have to do that a different way, e.g.: by using homebrew (or building from source)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) to download and maintain external open-source software for Mac OSX. The other popular option is [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh).

Once you install MacPorts, the following will install clang-16 (the latest available).

```
sudo port install clang-16
```

You need `/opt/local/bin` in your path, and then you can invoke clang with:

```
$ clang-mp-16 -v
clang version 16.0.3
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/local/libexec/llvm-16/bin
```

Comment: Any feedback on this answer? Was it useful for you?

Comment: That worked for me. I chose to use homebrew. Thanks for your answer.